# Upgrade to 20.04 LTS will not authenticate my password

Tags: password

I have not changed my password, I don't have the CAPS lock on, I've rebooted a number of times, I've been extremely careful about typing the correct password. I recently installed 20.04 as a trial on sda7 using my password and had no problems. I'm not sure what else to try. Perhaps there's a bug in 20.04.

Comment: Bugs are off-topic here.

Comment: In the password field, there's something that looks like an eye and has a line through it. Click it and it will show your password as you type it. Try that and see if maybe it's something as simple as the wrong keyboard layout.